# Mechanical Advantage of Static Double Pulleys

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, string, statics

For a set of two double pulleys, the force acting on each should be equal to the tension in the rope times the number of ropes connected to the individual pulley if I understand correctly.  In [this pulley system](https://www.mcmaster.com/2973T21/) on mcmaster, it looks as though the force acting on the upper pulley should be 5T (with T being tension) and the force acting on the lower 4T.  Can anyone explain why the specs give an effort (which should be the tension) of 85 lbf to give a lifting force of 500 lbf.  Why is it not 340 lbf (85*4).

Is my understanding of static pulley systems flawed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are correct.

I tried to find the mechanical advantage by using a FBD and got it to be 4:1. But just to be sure I poked around the internet a bit and found [this great site](https://www.globalsecurity.org/military/library/policy/army/fm/55-17/ch6.htm). The MA is given in section 6-8.3 .

Comment: That link is fabulous.  Thanks!